# Generic term for musical piece

Tags: music, generic-term

Colloquially, people use "song", even though "song" has actual specific properties.

What is a generic term for a musical piece? "Musical piece" is OK, but there really should be one that is a single word.

Even "piece" is not very semantic, and it's way too general. If you were to say "piece" without any context, it could be referring to anything: machine parts, body parts, abstract concept parts, etc. It implies other instances of its category. It already assumes a context of a musical composition if it's to be used for the purpose of a generic musical piece. (excuse the circular usage)

A "number" in my opinion is even worse semantically, as it has nothing to do with numerics. And it turns out that it implies that it's part of a collection, which is itself not generic enough http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_%28music%29 Even worse yet is that the term obscures the collection aspect of its implied meaning, whereas "piece" does not.

(aside: I find the phrase "did a number on you" to be such a semantic monstrosity of an idiom/phrase that it brings up visceral reactions of violence whenever I hear it)

"Composition" is too generic, as it can refer to writing, software, (etc.). It too can implies pieces built up together, albeit internally (e.g. fallacy of composition). Yes, music can be thought of as being made of many musical notes, pauses, (etc.), but that's a superfluous thing to point out, and not as core to the idea of it being music/sound/auditory.

Anyway, a generic term for a musical composition is needed that doesn't necessarily carry implications of it being part of a collection, and actually semantically implies sound/music so that it's not too general.

why has no one coined such a term in English, or if one exists, not used enough to not require such deep thinking to bring it to the forefront of consciousness?

Comment: What's wrong with *piece*? You might be able to use *composition*. Nowadays, a pretty common term is *track*.

Comment: What about *tune*, then?

Comment: In my opinion, why not just allow "song" to be this general term? It's not ideal, as it clashes with the specific properties of what "song" means, but I'm certain there are instances of something specific also being the term for its abstract class we use today. From an adoption-standpoint, it's already used that way by +95% of the population already anyway.

Comment: "Give me a piece." It's ambiguous and too generic. It could be referring to pie, and you wouldn't know unless you were provided the context, either before or afterward. The idea is to eliminate the need to explicitly give that extra context, containing all of the information about the scope within the term itself. It also implies it being a part of a collection. Even drawings are referred to as pieces, so it's too general. "Composition" holds the same problems, as it can refer to writing. I updated my OP.

Comment: In the same way that *Rollerblades* is a specific term used to refer to inline skates or *Kleenex* is a specific term used to refer to facial tissue, I don't see a problem using *song* to identify a musical piece. Only pedants will complain.

Comment: ^ I totally agree. "Tune" seems to be specific to the lack of accompaniment http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tune

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Ah,  but "song" isn't a trademark. ;)

Comment: @ahnbizcad - I think you have it backwards.  "Tune" is generally taken to mean the accompaniment, absent the vocal.

Comment: Beethoven's Ninth is a nice song.

Comment: Lol at the downvotes. @HotLicks Thank you for the correction! It seems tune is the best candidate from existing terms so far. Regarding why it should be a single term: it has an effect of cannonizing and snapping vagueness together. Just like how people coined the term dubstep, impressionism, etc. It's the fundamental function of words. Another reason is that when terms are cumbersome to say, it's not as sticky. These are aesthetic and functional arguments, but for good reason. If you didn't have the word "vehicle" and had to use "transportation machinery" all the time...

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that "musical piece" don't fit these criteria, and that I find it silly that such a ubiquitous and obviously needed term doesn't exist while every sub-species exists, necessitating a history lesson / encyclopedia session to even talk about it, feeding pedants. TBH, "musical piece" sounds cumbersome, pedantic, and unnecessarily awkwardly academic. It's just logical & sensible that there be a casual, normal word for such a concept used all the time. we're talking about music, not something obscure like insect -specific appendages, which have a dedicated term "antennae"

Comment: 2 people are attached to the phrase "did a number on you"

Comment: why is it that "tune" seems to be tightly tied to a melody? Maybe because it's only ever used that way (at least to my knowledge), despite the definition. Can anyone provide a counterexample?

Comment: Well, if you read the definition of "tune": [2 a :  a pleasing succession of musical tones :  melody](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tunehttp://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tune).

Comment: A tune is essentially the same thing as a melody. It doesn't work here. The term you are looking for is *"a piece of music"*. It doesn't imply that it's part of a collection any more than *"a piece of fruit"* or *"a piece of metal"* imply than an apple or a metal nugget are part of a collection. It's just the way uncountable nouns work in English.

Comment: but songs (generic) ARE countable.

you have one song. it ends. then you play the next one. every musician releases things in such units/chunks.

Yes, there are samples and fragments too, but songs are by FAR the most common and understood and expected unit of music worldwide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for "hyponym song" and found an interesting [page](http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/song.htm). While the page provides *song* six senses, only the first ("A short musical composition with words") seems to apply.

One section says:

> Hypernyms ("song" is a kind of...):
>   composition; musical composition; opus; piece; piece of music (a musical work that has been created)

I would go with any of these. It should be of little concern that *piece* can be used in other contexts, as it is a versatile word.

You can call Handel's Messiah a *piece* and you can call Justin Bieber's "U Smile" a *piece*. I would only call the former an *opus*.

As to the (possibly rhetorical) question on why no one has coined a hypernym of *song*. The hyponyms convey information about the genre, pedigree, length, or quality of the piece. *Song* does not. *Track* does not. One wouldn't call Handel's Messiah a *ditty* or Justin Bieber's "U Smile" a *magnum opus*, except for comic effect.

Comment: excellent research and great points. It adds a lot to the discussion. I will counter your excellent points that hypernyms also have value. To say that hyponyms carry information while hypernyms do not is just as valid and neither-here-nor-there as saying hypernyms allow for generality without necessitating specifics while hyponyms do not. My point is that hypernyms and hyponyms each have their utility, and the appropriate level of abstraction (including not being too abstract, like "piece") is the point of language and terms. Imagine if there was no word "parent",and only "grandparent" existed

Comment: and whenever you used the only term that exists, "grandparent", you had to ask or find out more whether it was the adjacent generation or any unspecified ancestor that was being referred to. That's how it is with "piece" or "work". "Musical piece" technically does the trick, but I argue that it's aesthetically a mouthful and cumbersome, which is somewhat subjective.

Comment: You're welcome! I would rather read a book than listen to it on CD, but in the case of http://daniellevitin.com/publicpage/books/the-world-in-six-songs/ I would make an exception: he embeds musical examples in the narrative. If you do read (or listen to) the book, maybe it will become clear why Levitin chose the word "song" for the title.

Comment: Oh, "song" is definitely the appropriate choice there. I'll just say that he didn't really have a choice because other co-hyponyms aren't appropriate, and there is no hypernym! This is actually an excellent example of why "piece", "work", or "musical piece" are lacking. Using any of these overly generic, or cumbersome terms are not catchy or casual enough for marketability... which is exactly my point that is one reason for voicing the lack of a much needed, non-existent term!

Answer (score 3):

I'd need context, but go with "piece" or "work" for most uses. If you're looking for a term that includes arias, symphonies, songs, mouth music, smooth jazz, and dubstep—I doubt there is one. We do have the term "oeuvre", but when used (rarely) it tends to refer to a person's total body of work. (See what I did there, with "work"?)

Comment: There should be one.

Comment: "Piece" and "work" and "opus" which is just latin for work, are all too general, and can refer to things beyond music as mentioned in the OP. You need to provide additional context just to let people know you're talking about music after you use any of those terms.

Comment: I don't see what you did with "work". It still necessitated context to convey that the over-general term was limited to musical work. A musician could have also been known for lyrics and poetry, which doesn't necessarily get excluded the way you used the term. Thus my point stands. I'm having trouble wording it that doesn't seem to convey hostility, especially since I expressed it about other things in the OP, but please forgive me; I can't seem to find the words.

Comment: my statue. my car, my desk are all pieces and also a works.
We want something specific to music. One that isn't overly broad. Seems like this would be a no brainer to have, when everyone knows and thinks in terms of the concept that has no word.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a piece of classical music, it is often called an **opus**. It is not too general as you suggested because the word's primary meaning in English is not "work in general" but "a piece of music written by a major composer".

If you want to be specific, the German word **lied** and the French word **chanson** have both incorporated into English.

An **étude** is a "piece of music built on a technical motive but played for its artistic value". It can also be found in the English dictionary.

Comment: The words *lied* and *chanson* both mean *song* in their native languages, and usually aren't used for things other than songs (and usually ones in German and French, at that).

Comment: opus - any artistic work, especially one on a large scale. It's not limited to music or auditory work. It also conveys magnitude to the everyday ear, making it not suitable for generic intended use. I'm seriously baffled faith-broken by the lack of this word in English.